# store.dispatch is not updating the state in redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have the component just only add and minus button. If I'm using `useDispatch` from `react-redux` it will update the redux state. The problem is when I'm using `store.dispatch()` it will not updating the state.

**component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment';
import { FlatList, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Paragraph, Divider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import AppContainer from '../Common/AppContainer';
import LinearButton from '../Common/Button';
import translation from '../../Util/Translation';
import styles from '../../Components/Styles/Notification/Notification';
import NotificationAction from '../../Redux/Notification/Actions';
import createStore from '../../Redux/CreateStore';

const { t } = translation;

const NotificationScreen = (props) => {
  const { NotificationDetails, onSendNotificationPress } = { ...props };
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.notificationReducer);
  const { store } = createStore();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const addPress = () => {
    store.dispatch(NotificationAction.add(23));
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <AppContainer title={t('NOTIFICATION')} leftIcon="ios-arrow-back" isLeft>
        <FlatList
          data={NotificationDetails.sort((_val, $val) => new Date($val.data) - new Date(_val.data))}
          keyExtractor={(item, i) => i.toString()}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Divider />}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.fltLst}>
                <View style={styles.flt}>
                  <View style={styles.drtn}>
                    <Text style={styles.hdr}>Notification</Text>
                    <Paragraph> {moment(item.data).startOf().fromNow()}</Paragraph>
                  </View>
                  <Text>{item.Subscriber_Status}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </AppContainer>
      <View style={styles.buttonView}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <LinearButton title={t('SENDNOTIFICATION')} onPress={onSendNotificationPress} />
        </View>
        <Button title="Add" onPress={addPress} />
        <Text style={[styles.hdr, { alignSelf: 'center' }]}> {count}</Text>
        <Button title="Remove" />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default NotificationScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `store.`. Just use `dispatch(actions.someFunc(params))`:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Comment: I want to dispatch the action instead of useDispatch

Comment: Note the documentation reference to this hook: "This hook returns a reference to the dispatch function from the Redux store. You may use it to dispatch actions as needed."

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
// then further
dispatch(NotificationAction.add(23))
```

**OR**

You have to import the same store which you pass in the `StoreProvider`
in your question you are making a new instance of store verbatim like so:
`const { store } = createStore();`
You should not create multiple instances of the store. If you have more than one instances then the value would update in any one of the instance(s) rather than in the one you passed in the provider for.